# Selectively remove all occurrences from a list of lists based off of another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.6

I've been looking for hours and haven't been able to find ***exactly*** what I need, so I thought I'd ask.  I'm trying to remove elements from a list of lists based on another list of dictionaries.  I have a list of items that I don't want to appear in my list of lists.

```
exclude_list = [{'arb_field_1': '0', 'arb_field_2': '59',
                 'surrogate_key': '0502f5fb0731b5afc'},
                {'arb_field_1': '0', 'arb_field_2': '62',
                 'surrogate_key': '1676c663914864973'},
                {'arb_field_1': '0', 'arb_field_2': '62',
                 'surrogate_key': '2fc1ed4adffbb635'}]
```

Then I have my primary list, which I want to delete elements from based on the surrogate_key in the exclude list of dictionaries.

```
prim_list = [['0502f5fb0731b5afc', 'bla_bla_bla', 'foo_bar1'],
             ['0502f5fb0731b5afc', 'john_smith', 'dummy_data_elem1'],
             ['002b2a71e8b514', '5450464', 'data_i_dont_care_about'],
             ['2fc1ed4adffbb635', '05d3mh', 'obfuscated_field1'],
             ['12319618913119', 'granny_apples', 'filler_filler']]
```

I have the following loop which works (doesn't feel very pythonic, but I'm new to Python so I'm open to suggestions on that).. but ***only*** deletes one instance of the match, where I need to delete ***all*** instances of the match.

```
for exclude_list_item in exclude_list:
    for i, v in enumerate(prim_list):
        if v[0] == exclude_list_item.get('surrogate_key'):
            prim_list.remove(prim_list[i])
```

What I want to end up with is a list of lists like this:

```
prim_list = [['002b2a71e8b514', '5450464', 'data_i_dont_care_about'],
             ['12319618913119', 'granny_apples', 'filler_filler']]
```

Comment: As an aside, Python 2.6 came out like a decade ago. Python 2 is already at it's end-of-life in 2020. Maybe it's time to switch to Python 3, or at least, the current version of Python 2.7.

Comment: not helpful.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you would like remove to remove all occurrences of an `exclude_list_item`, not only the first one?

I suggest to construct a new list instead. So, you iterate over the list, and append the item to a a new list item if it is not in your exclude list.

The reason is that removing from a list is computationally more expensive than removing multiple random items.

```
new_prim_list = []
for v in prim_list:
    for exclude_list_item in exclude_list:
        if v[0] == exclude_list_item.get('surrogate_key'):
             break
    else:
        new_prim_list.append(v)
prim_list = new_prim_list
```

Edit: Fix the code

Note that this does not affect other references to the list, so if you want to modify the list as part of function, then the caller won't see the modifications in his list. The same problem occurs with any solution that directly assigns a new array to `prim_list`,
like any constructs of the form

```
prim_list = [...]
```

Comment: This approach worked, but I went with juanpa.arrivillaga's solution only because it used the same list instead of creating a new one

Answer (score 1):

Using `list.remove` removes the *first instance* from your list, not every instance. To make things easy, let's do a single pass where we accumulate the `surrogate_key`s into a set for efficient membership testing:

```
>>> exclude_list = [{'arb_field_1': '0', 'arb_field_2': '59', 'surrogate_key': '0502f5fb0731b5afc'}, {'arb_field_1': '0', 'arb_field_2': '62', 'surrogate_key': '1676c663914864973'}, {'arb_field_1': '0', 'arb_field_2': '62', 'surrogate_key': '2fc1ed4adffbb635'}]
>>> prim_list = [['0502f5fb0731b5afc', 'bla_bla_bla', 'foo_bar1'], ['0502f5fb0731b5afc', 'john_smith', 'dummy_data_elem1'], ['002b2a71e8b514', '5450464', 'data_i_dont_care_about'], ['2fc1ed4adffbb635', '05d3mh', 'obfuscated_field1'], ['12319618913119', 'granny_apples', 'filler_filler']]
>>> exclude_key = set()
>>> for d in exclude_list:
...     key = d.get('surrogate_key')
...     if key is not None:
...         exclude_key.add(key)
...
```

Then, simply filter using a list-comprehension:

```
>>> prim_list = [sub for sub in prim_list if sub[0] not in exclude_key]
>>> prim_list
[['002b2a71e8b514', '5450464', 'data_i_dont_care_about'], ['12319618913119', 'granny_apples', 'filler_filler']]
```

Answer (score 1):

First filter the surrogate keys in some set.

```
set_surr = set( [i.get('surrogate_key') for i in exclude_list] )
```

Now we can create new list and use above set as lookup.

```
prim_list = [ i for i in prim_list if i[0] not in set_surr ]
```

One liner solution :

```
prim_list = [ i for i in prim_list if i[0] not in set( [j.get('surrogate_key') for j in exclude_list] ) ]
```